# Uwsgi Upstart- Virtual Environment Variables Are Not Accessable

Tags: django, uwsgi

I am using Django 1.6 and Uwsgi. I  do not want to run Uwsgi in emperor mode. I want to run Uwsgi as a upstart job. My Django site is in a virtual environment. Everything works out good except I have some variables that are extracted from `.virtualenvs/community/bin/activate` that are used in `settings/production.py`. Running uwsgi from upstart, it is able to access the virtualenviroment with no issues. However, these variables are not available in the environment. How can I make it to where the variables are in the virtual environment when uwsgi is ran from upstart?

root@community:/home/community/uwsgi# cat /home/community/.virtualenvs/community/bin/activate

```
export DB_NAME="blah"
export DB_USER="foo"
export DB_PASS="bar"
export DB_HOST="localhost"
```

Django settings production.py

```
########## DATABASE CONFIGURATION
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': get_env_variable('DB_NAME'),  # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': get_env_variable('DB_USER'),  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': get_env_variable('DB_PASS'),  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': get_env_variable('DB_HOST'),  # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',  # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
```

},
}

root@community:/home/community/uwsgi# cat community_forums.ini

```
[uwsgi]
chdir = /home/community/community-forums/bot_server
module = bot_server.wsgi:application
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=bot_server.settings.production
master = 1
pidfile = /tmp/project-master.pid
socket = 127.0.0.1:3031
processes = 5
harakiri = 20 
max-requests = 5000
vacuum = 1
logto = /var/tmp/uwsgi.log
virtualenv = /home/community/.virtualenvs/community
```

root@community:/home/community/uwsgi# cat /etc/init/uwsgi.conf

```
#This version is for Community Servic

description "uwsgi tiny instance"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

exec uwsgi --die-on-term --ini /home/community/uwsgi/community_forums.ini

root@community:/home/community/uwsgi#
```

Answer (score 1):

Upstart Environment Variables:

```
#This version is for Community Servic

description "uwsgi tiny instance"

env DB_NAME="blah"
env DB_USER="foo"
env DB_PASS="bar"
env DB_HOST="localhost"

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [06]

exec uwsgi --die-on-term --ini /home/community/uwsgi/community_forums.ini
```

See [this chapter of the book](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#environment-variables): "Upstart Intro, Cookbook and Best Practises"